# Clearing certain activity variables with onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I'm creating a simple Android app with 2 Activities. Activity B displays a bunch of data passed from A. When the user press the back button from B I need to clear some variables in order to not duplicate the data shown on B, but both variables I'm erasing on onResume() aren't clearing at all. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<Camarera> camareras = new ArrayList<Camarera>();
List<String> resultados = new ArrayList<String>();

int camHabs = 0;

Button boton;

TextView dinero;
TextView camarera1, camarera2, camarera3, camarera4, camarera5;

EditText hora1, hora2, hora3, hora4, hora5;
EditText resta1, resta2, resta3, resta4, resta5;

Switch switch1, switch2, switch3, switch4, switch5;

@Override
public void onResume()
{  
    super.onResume();
    resultados = new ArrayList<>();
    camHabs = 0;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Resumiendo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Boton);

    camHabs = 0;

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calcular();
        }
    });
}

void Calcular(){

    dinero = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Dinero);

    camarera1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Camarera1);
    camarera2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Camarera2);
    camarera3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Camarera3);
    camarera4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Camarera4);
    camarera5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Camarera5);

    hora1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Horas1);
    hora2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Horas2);
    hora3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Horas3);
    hora4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Horas4);
    hora5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Horas5);

    resta1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Resta1);
    resta2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Resta2);
    resta3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Resta3);
    resta4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Resta4);
    resta5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.C_Resta5);

    switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.C_Switch1);
    switch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.C_Switch2);
    switch3 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.C_Switch3);
    switch4 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.C_Switch4);
    switch5 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.C_Switch5);


    List<TextView> nombres = Arrays.asList(camarera1, camarera2, camarera3, camarera4, camarera5);
    List<EditText> horas = Arrays.asList(hora1, hora2, hora3, hora4, hora5);
    List<EditText> restas = Arrays.asList(resta1, resta2, resta3, resta4, resta5);
    List switches = Arrays.asList(switch1, switch2, switch3, switch4, switch5);

    int resultado;
    int maxHoras = 0;
    int Dinero = Integer.parseInt(dinero.getText().toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.size(); i++) {
        Camarera cam = new Camarera();

        cam.SetNombre(nombres.get(i).getText().toString());
        cam.SetHoras(horas.get(i).getText().toString());
        maxHoras += cam.GetHoras();
        cam.SetResta(restas.get(i).getText().toString());
        Switch var = (Switch) switches.get(i);
        cam.activa = var.isChecked();

        camareras.add(cam);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < camareras.size(); i++) {
            Camarera cam = camareras.get(i);

            if (cam.activa) {
                camHabs++;
                if (cam.error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cam.error_S, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }


                resultado = ((cam.GetHoras() * Dinero) / maxHoras) - cam.GetResta();
                resultados.add(cam.GetNombre() + " se lleva " + resultado + "€");
            }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tabla.class);
    intent.putExtra("lista", (ArrayList<String>) resultados);
    intent.putExtra("habs", camHabs);
    startActivity(intent);



}
```

Could you help me please? Been stuck with this the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Try to equal them to null into on Resume and then after that recreate the empty value as you've already done. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on `OnResume`:

> Be aware that the system calls this method every time your activity comes into the foreground, including when it's created for the first time.

It is even called when you press home button/switch apps, so I don't think it is a good idea to do this here.

Why not just do it before you call your `startActivity` call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tabla.class);
intent.putExtra("lista", (ArrayList<String>) resultados);
intent.putExtra("habs", camHabs);

//Reset variables here
resultados = new ArrayList<>();
camHabs = 0;

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error wasn't on those two variables, it was on a third one called "camareras" I wasn't clearing it and because I use it in each cycle it would add again and again to "camHabs".

Thanks anyways!